# Getting different roles for an employee

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am retrieving different roles for an employee using a dynamic query :

```
DECLARE @roles NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
    DECLARE @EmployeeId NVARCHAR(MAX)='';
    DECLARE  @Roles_Employee TABLE
(
     EmployeeId NVARCHAR(MAX),
     Scope NVARCHAR(MAX)
);


    SELECT @EmployeeId=@EmployeeId+(SELECT DISTINCT CAST(e.EmployeeId as nvarchar(255))  FROM Employee e
    LEFT JOIN Employee_Role er2 ON e.EmployeeId=er2.EmployeeId
    WHERE e.EmployeeId=54)
    ,
    @roles=@roles+ ('Select '+isnull(er.ColumnName,'*')+' from '+er.SchemaName+'.'+er.TableName+' where '+kcu.COLUMN_NAME +'='+er1.ValueId )

       from [Function].[Role] er 
        left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc on 
            tc.TABLE_NAME=er.TableName and tc.TABLE_SCHEMA=er.SchemaName
       left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu on kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME=tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        left JOIN Employee_Role er1 ON er.EntityRoleId = er1.RoleId
        left  JOIN Employee e ON er1.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
    where e.EmployeeId=54 AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY' AND er1.ValueId !=0 AND er1.ValueId IS NOT NULL;
    INSERT INTO @Roles_Employee(EmployeeId,Scope)

  EXEC sp_executesql @roles;
  SELECT EmployeeId,Scope FROM @Roles_Employee;
```

and I am getting this error :

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

My expected output :

```
EmployeeId Scope
54         Commercial Collaboration - Head Of
54         Gardening
54         Portage
```

**EDIT** 
 I can get the different roles for an employee like below :

```
DECLARE @roles NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
        DECLARE @table TABLE
    (
        Scope NVARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    SELECT @roles=@roles+ 'Select '+isnull(er.ColumnName,'*')+' from '+er.SchemaName+'.'+er.TableName+' where '+kcu.COLUMN_NAME +'='+er1.ValueId 


       from [Function].[Role] er 
        left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc on 
            tc.TABLE_NAME=er.TableName and tc.TABLE_SCHEMA=er.SchemaName
       left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu on kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME=tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        left JOIN Employee_Role er1 ON er.EntityRoleId = er1.RoleId
        left  JOIN Employee e ON er1.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
    where e.EmployeeId=54 AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY' AND er1.ValueId !=0 AND er1.ValueId IS NOT NULL

    INSERT INTO @table(Scope)
  EXEC sp_executesql @roles;

  SELECT * FROM @table
```

Result of my query :

```
Scope
Commercial Collaboration - Head Of
Gardening
Portage
```

I want to get the EmployeeId in an EmployeeId column with the Scope so my output will be :

```
EmployeeId Scope
    54         Commercial Collaboration - Head Of
    54         Gardening
    54         Portage
```

**Resukt of PRINT :**

```
545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454545454
Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=156Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=207Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=60Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=74Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=89Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=187Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=34Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=155Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=17Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=18Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=20Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=26Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=34Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=57Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=58Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=62Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=155Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=17Select Label from dbo.Employee_Department where DepartmentId=74Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=111Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=128Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=148Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=149Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=150Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=161Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=170Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=171Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=172Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=181Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=182Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=187Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=231Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=246Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=249Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=255Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=258Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=259Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=260Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=261Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=282Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=284Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=285Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=292Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=30Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=314Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=317Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=320Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=322Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=323Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=324Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=325Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=332Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=333Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=346Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=347Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=348Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=349Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=358Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=359Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=4Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=413Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=421Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=422Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=423Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=445Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=476Select AccountId from Treasury.Account where AccountId=50Select AccountId f
```

Comment: `PRINT @roles;` is your friend here. Debug the dynamic SQL that is being executed, and then debug the query that creates it. We can't run your SQL, so there's little we can do to actually help you here.

Comment: I think the problem is in this line: `where '+kcu.COLUMN_NAME +'='+er1.ValueId` if you have a varchar you must surround the value with *'value'*

Comment: But you omitted the result of `@PRINT @roles;`...

Comment: What's that `545454...`? and `...156Select...` is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your dynamic SQL is `@roles` and doesn't include the `EmployeeID`

Since the employeeID seems to be a constant value for all your `Scope`, a solution is to include this value hard-coded on your dynamic SQL as an additional column.

First separate the EmployeeID `SELECT` from the roles `SELECT`.

```
SET @EmployeeId = (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        CAST(e.EmployeeId as nvarchar(255)) 
    FROM 
        Employee e
        LEFT JOIN Employee_Role er2 ON e.EmployeeId=er2.EmployeeId
    WHERE 
        e.EmployeeId=54)
```

Then imprint it's value on the roles `SELECT`:

```
SELECT 
    @roles = @roles 
        + 'Select '
        + '''' + @EmployeeId + ''' AS EmployeeID, ' -- Add a new hard-coded column on the DynamicSQL
        + isnull(er.ColumnName,'*')
        + ' from ' + er.SchemaName + '.' + er.TableName
        + ' where '
        + kcu.COLUMN_NAME + '=' + er1.ValueId 
from 
    [Function].[Role] er 
    left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc on tc.TABLE_NAME=er.TableName and tc.TABLE_SCHEMA=er.SchemaName
    left join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE kcu on kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME=tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    left JOIN Employee_Role er1 ON er.EntityRoleId = er1.RoleId
    left  JOIN Employee e ON er1.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
where 
    e.EmployeeId=54 AND 
    tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='PRIMARY KEY' AND 
    er1.ValueId !=0 AND er1.ValueId IS NOT NULL;
```